# Redirecting Rails Route on Bad CSV Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rspec

I'm having trouble getting my RSpec tests with CSV formatting to work.

My controller has a before_filter for authenticating the current user (devise). It works perfectly for this code **get :index :format => :html** however, when I need to test my **get :index :format => :csv** route, it is returning a 401 instead of redirecting. This is correct, the authentication is still working, but it's not redirecting.

Why isn't the controller redirecting the unauthorized person to the sign-in page when they hit **http://localhost.com/rooms.csv** but properly redirects the user if they hit **http://localhost.com/rooms**?

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    respond_to do |format|

      format.html do
        @rooms = current_user.rooms
      end

      format.csv do
        # all the stuff to create a CSV
      end
    end
  end



describe 'GET index format CSV' do

  let(:patrick){ Fabricate(:user) }

  before { sign_in :user, patrick; patrick.confirm;}

  it_behaves_like "requires sign in" do
    let(:action) { get :index, :format => :csv }
  end
end

Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <401>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that Devise responds to CSV as if it was an API request - if you for example are requesting JSON a 302 Found response would not be very helpful.

Comment: I think you could get Devise to redirect by adding CSV to its navigable  formats. `config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :csv]`